# iOS: Changing a UIImageView by pressing an UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uibutton

I'm making a very simple game. I have a UIButton and an UIImageView. What I'm trying to do is that when the user presses the button, it will change the image to another image and then back to the original image, to simulate an animation (Character moving)

I have this code:

file.m

```
{

IBOutlet UIImageView *image1;
IBOutlet UIButton *button;

}

-(IBAction)button:(id)sender;
```

file.h

```
-(IBAction)button:(id)sender{

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                 animations:^{

                    image1.alpha = 0.1f;


                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"]; 

                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f
                                      animations:^{

                                          image1.alpha = 1.0f;

                                      } completion:^ (BOOL finished) {

                                         image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
                                      }];

                 }];


}
```

When I open the iOS simulator and press the button, the image dissolves, then reappears  and then does the animation. The problem is that I don't want it to dissolve, I just want to show the animation. How do I prevent this from happening? Is it because I'm using alpha properties?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by you don't want it to dissolve, but you do want the animation?  The only property you are animating is the alpha, which will cause a fade effect

Comment: You're animating a change in alpha, of course its going to show a dissolve transition.

Comment: I want the image to do the animation without the fade effect. I removed the alpha property but now the animation is not showing the way its supposed to show

Comment: So, you want the image to swap without fading?

Comment: I fixed it, thank you for your help! I had to remove the alpha property and make a few changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following code to do what I ***think*** is what you need (shown here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vtcyw0n257tgihx/fade.mov?dl=0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(test)];

    iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 150, 150)];
    iv.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red"];
    [self.view addSubview:iv];
}

- (void)test {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
        iv.alpha = 0.0f;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        iv.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue"];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
            iv.alpha = 1.0f;
        } completion:^ (BOOL finished) {

            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
                iv.alpha = 0.0f;
            } completion:^ (BOOL finished) {
                iv.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red"];

                [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
                    iv.alpha = 1.0f;
                } completion:nil];
            }];
        }];

    }];
}
```

You need to break it down into four parts. First you need to fade the original image out, change it to the second image, fade the second image in, fade the second image out, change back to the original image, then fade it back in.